# how se a selected option for a Yii dropdownlist then disable it?

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

i'm trying to select a value as selected for a dropdown list in Yii framework then disable it, i tried the below code, it was successfully disabled but value was not set, i even tried to swap between disabling option and setting the selected value, the value was selected but DDL not disabled,i appreciate any help, thanks.

```
    if($model->isNewRecord)
    {
      echo $form->dropDownList($model,'categoryId', CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),array('disabled'=>'disabled'),array('options' => array($CatId=>array('selected'=>true))) );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply mark your desired option as selected like below:

```
$model->categoryId=$CatId; //before rendering dropdown
```

And remove the following array:

```
array('options' => array($CatId=>array('selected'=>true)))
```

Comment: so you mean that $model->categoryId = $CatId will store the value without having to set it from the dropdown list?

Comment: I assumed that `$CatId` is an option that you have already got it. If the `$CatId` is exists in `CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')` it will be selected by default, since you have set it in your model.